# Temporarily suspending event handling

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I use a function to bind code to several elements at once. Elsewhere in my application I want to suspend this binding under certain circumstances, and to restore it in others. Here's my code:

```
function populate_modal(x) {

    var button_id = '#button_page' + x;
    var page_id = '#course_intro_page' + x;

    $(button_id).on('click', function() {   

        var a = $(page_id).html(); 
        $('.fadeandscale_inner').html(a); 

    });

}

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    populate_modal(i);
}
```

How to achieve what I want? It should look like:

```
if (condition) {
    // suspend all code associated with "#button_page" buttons, and bind some other code to these buttons
}
else {
    // switch back to default code associated with buttons
}
```

Comment: filtering regarding your condition inside click handler (or maybe more suitable, delegate event), btw, use common class to bind handler

Comment: Do you mean the off method? http://api.jquery.com/off/ "The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on(). See the discussion of delegated and directly bound events on that page for more information. Calling .off() with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements. Specific event handlers can be removed on elements by providing combinations of event names, namespaces, selectors, or handler function names."

Answer (score 0):

You could have a generic class in order to be able to handle all of the buttons, but
you could also add the class when the binding occurs.

Check this:

```
function populate_modal(x) {

    var button_id = '#button_page' + x;
    var page_id = '#course_intro_page' + x;

    //add class to handle event bind removal
    $( button_id ).addClass( 'bindedButton' );

    $(button_id).on('click', function() {   

        var a = $(page_id).html(); 
        $('.fadeandscale_inner').html(a); 

    });

}

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    populate_modal(i);
}

if (condition) {
    $( '.bindedButton' ).off( 'click' );
}
else {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
       populate_modal(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the "if(condition){ " line is only executed once on page load, whether I want to be able to switch on and off the original binding any number of times after page load.